When I tried to automate apple login screen it get stucked after entering user name in cypress
The issue screenhot is here also  I have tried the putting wait but the issue is not resolved
Cypress image of automation
Also I have tried this solution from github cypress issues suggested by one of the cypress member https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/29345
    /// <reference types="cypress" />
//cypress - spec

describe('Paid Ticket Test Suite', () => {

    it('Login to mds', function () {

        cy.visit("https://test.milliondollarsellers.com/")

        cy.get('.apple-btn').click()

        cy.origin("https://appleid.apple.com/auth/", () => {

            cy.wait(10000)
            cy.get('#account_name_text_field').blur({ force: true })
            cy.wait(10000)
            // cy.get('#account_name_text_field').type("email")

            cy.get('#account_name_text_field').type("email")
            cy.wait(10000)
            /* cy.get('#account_name_text_field').focus()
            cy.wait(10000)
            cy.get('#account_name_text_field').blur() */

            cy.get('#sign-in .shared-icon.icon_sign_in').click()
            cy.wait(10000)
            cy.get("#password_text_field").then(($el) => {
                console.log("Issue is ", $el); // Log the element to the console
            }).type('User@123');

            //cy.get('#password_text_field').should('be.visible').type('User@123')

            //cy.get('.shared-icon').click()

            //cy.pause()
            //cy.contains('button', 'Trust').click()

        })


    })

}) 

Here the thing i want to automate

Locate the email field text area and enter email id

Then click on arrow icon so that password field become visible

Then enter the password and then again click on arrow icon I get navigated to next screen where OTP will be asked and Then I will be logged in



You could improve the question and increase chance of an answer by posting the test as code instead of (or as well as) an image.

Thanks @JanetSuzman I have edited and added code snippet

Please someone help
